# angular rxjs do something after all observable sended without subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'll use async pipe, will not run subscribe method.

Like concat 1 to 10 and slice every 3 number to a new array.

```js
import { timer, concat, interval, range } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, map, tap, take, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

const sliceEveryN = (a,b) => console.log('Method runs')
const arr = []
const source = range(1, 5); // [1..5]
const source2 = range(6, 5); // [6..10]
const final = concat(source, source2).pipe(
 map(v => arr.push(v))
 ).pipe(
 // I want to this at last, not every observable sent
 map(v => sliceEveryN(3, v)) // [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10]]
 )
```

This will run the sliceEveryN method ten times, expect once.

Comment: Async pipe subscribes to the observable.

Comment: you can replace sliceEveryN by buffer ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `bufferCount(N)` will buffer N emitions and emit and aggregated array:

> Collect emitted values until provided number is fulfilled, emit as array

```
const final = concat(source, source2).pipe(
    tap(v => arr.push(v)),
    bufferCount(3),
    tap(v => console.log(v))
);
```

This will emit an array of every 3 values and print them to console.

Comment: I tested， sliceEveryN output 10 times.

Comment: i think i understand what you wanted to achieve, i changed my answer

Comment: @AlonYampolski i think that the `arr` is not needed if he use `buffer`.

Comment: @ElmaCherb using buffer will not give the desired result of groups of 3 as shown in the question: `[1,2,3], [4,5,6]...`

Comment: Yes i know, i'am talking about the solution with `buffer` in general. Of course we need to use its variante `bufferCount` as you've shown. With this solution he will not need the `arr` variable. But if he need it absolutely then the initialization must be inside a `defer` operator.

Comment: @ElmaCherb you're correct, basically there is no need for the `arr` variable. since i was not sure of its purpose i left it :)